# MySQL - CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS ...
```

A new user is created without a problem. An existing user returns that error, but the docs read that [`CREATE USER` for MySQL > 5.7.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html) supports it.

MySQL Version is

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.11, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

Sample

```
<root:none> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
--------------
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar'
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

<root:none> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
--------------
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar'
--------------

ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'foo'@'localhost'
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Here `create user` failed as user is already exists

Comment: I expect that `IF NOT EXISTS` is supposed to handle this error just as it does everywhere else. Is this a known bug or am I not using it correctly?

Comment: Is strict sql mode enabled?

Comment: I am not sure about whether it is handled or not but there are ways by which you can handle this. Like you can use `select * from user where user='name';` or you can take count from this query. **OR** As you are creating user you have to give grants to user. In mysql you can use grant command to create user if not already created like `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES  ON db_name.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;` Grant will create user if not already exists.

Comment: I appreciate that there are other ways to achieve the same result. I am keen to understand why `IF NOT EXISTS` doesn't work as documented.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql create user if not exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13357760/608639)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` throws an error if you use the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause and the user does exist. It does not throw an error and works as expected if you do not use the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause.

```
mysql> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation CREATE USER failed for 'foo'@'localhost'

mysql> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

From 5.7.8, instead of using `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS`, you can use `DROP USER IF EXISTS` before calling `CREATE USER` with the `IDENTIFIED BY` clause.

```
mysql> DROP USER 'foo'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP USER 'foo'@'localhost';
ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation DROP USER failed for 'foo'@'localhost'

mysql> DROP USER IF EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

The other option is to create the user first and then set the password after the user is created.

```
mysql> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'foo'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'foo'@'localhost' = 'bar';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: `DROP USER IF EXISTS` followed by `CREATE USER IDENTIFIED BY ...` is very different from `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS IDENTIFIED BY ...` and has some seriously un-desireable consequences. The former is way more dangerous than the latter. It was unclear to me that `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` with `IDENTIFIED BY` was intentionally not implemented. Thank you for the comments. I appreciate the alternate suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: You can use the `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` without the `IDENTIFIED CLAUSE`. Then use `SET PASSWORD FOR` to set the password.

Comment: Answer accepted because it helps with the problem at hand. It is unclear if the behaviour is intended or buggy.

Comment: I thought SQL was supposed to be standard. Why is it there's no standard way to do it that works everywhere? (During testing, 3 of 4 MySQL/MariaDB systems do things differently)

Answer (score -2):

Try doing a FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost';
```

You can check the link. It might help you

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008610/error-1396-hy000-operation-create-user-failed-for-usernamelocalhost-iden)

Comment: Does this mean that `CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS` is buggy and known as such?